# What is the basis for the custom to stand or sit by Vayivarech Dovid?

Tags: minhag, shacharis-morning-prayer, standing-sitting, pesukei-dezimra

What is the basis for the customs to either stand or to sit for Vayivarech Dovid?

Comment: Two commentless downvotes? This question is both on-topic and well-formulated.

Comment: @Lee Well-formulated? I don't think so.

Comment: @DoubleAA I think the intelligent answer proves the legitimacy of the question.

Comment: @AlBerko I don't know what that means

Comment: @AlBerko Legitimate != well-formulated. Thanks for the compliment anyway.

Comment: @DoubleAA How would you have formulated it better?  What is your concern?

Answer (score 8):

To stand for Vayevarech David is codified by the [Rema, OC 51:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.51.7):

> ונהגו לעמוד כשאומרים ברוך שאמר ויברך דוד וישתבח:
>
> The custom is to stand when they say Baruch She’amar, Vayivarech David, and Yishtabach.

Rema writes similarly in his [Darchei Moshe ad. loc. §8](https://www.sefaria.org/Darchei_Moshe,_Orach_Chaim.51.8.1):

> מהרי"ל לא היה עומד בשעה שאמר הפסוקים של לך ה' הגדולה כו' אבל המנהג עכשיו לעמוד מויברך דוד עד תפארתך:
>
> Maharil did not stand when he said the Pesukim of Lecha Hashem, but the custom now is to stand from Vayivarech David until “tifartecha.”

[Kaf HaChaim ad. loc. §43](https://www.sefaria.org/Kaf_HaChayim_on_Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.51.43.1) says this was also the opinion of the Arizal as well (plus the next four words):

> וכ"כ האר"י ז"ל בשער הכוונות בענין תפלת השחר די"ח ע"ג וז"ל צריך לקום מעומד מן ויברך דיד וכו' עד אתה הוא ה' האלהים אשר בחרת באברם וכו' ועד בכלל להיות כי שם אהיה רמוז בר"ת אתה הוא ה' האלהים וכו' וכל אהיה הוא בכתר ולכן צריך לקום מעומד עד סוף ארבעה תיבות הנז' בלבד עכ"ל.
>
> Similarly did the Arizal write in Sha’ar HaKavanos regarding Tefillas HaShachar: “One must stand from Vayivarech David...until Atah hu Hashem HaElokim asher bacharta beAvram, inclusive. This is because the Name Ehyeh is hinted in the initials of Atah hu Hashem HaElokim, and all [mentions of] Ehyeh are with a crown(?). Therefore one must stand until the end of these four words alone.

Similarly [Magen Avraham ad. loc. §9](https://www.sefaria.org/Magen_Avraham.51.9) writes more succinctly, quoting the same source:

> ויברך דוד. בויברך דוד יעמוד עד שיאמר אתה הוא ה' האלקים ויכוין ר"ת אהי"ה ואח"כ ישב [הכוונות].
>
> In Vayivarech David one should stand until he says “Atah hu Hashem HaElokim,” and he should focus on the initials Ehyeh and then sit.

Those who sit perhaps rely on the Maharil, or perhaps the Shulchan Aruch who’s silent on the topic, or perhaps the [Biur HaGra ad. loc. DH v’nahagu](https://www.sefaria.org/Beur_HaGra_on_Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.51.7.5):

> ונהגו כו'. לחומרא בעלמא
>
> As a general stringency

indicating that it’s not a strict requirement. I can’t find anyone who says explicitly *not* to stand, only these sources which imply either explicitly or implicitly that it’s not required.

Comment: Re "later", the _Rama_ and the _Ari_ lived at the same time. Also, you seen to have missed the word "וכו׳" in the כה״ח: it's not just the next few words.

Comment: @msh210 Good catch on the “later.” I didn’t miss the וכו - that’s why I included the ellipsis in the translation.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the one in "עד אתה הוא ה' האלהים אשר בחרת באברם **וכו'** ועד בכלל"